# You must select at least one Listed Platform to display

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am creating a simple app, I am getting this error when I try to save changes:

"You must select at least one Listed Platform to display."

please see the screen shot here:

http://panstickers.com.au/webimages/fb_error.gif

I tried to google, but couldn't find anythings. Please help.

Many thanks

Comment: You need to define if your app is canvas/website/ios/android, and tell facebook which of those implementations you want displayed

Answer (score 0):

As per:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/appcenter/

You first have to go to the settings page and specify one of the options at the bottom with the tick marks.