# You must choose at least one platform to be displayed

Tags: ios, facebook

On the advanced tab, when I try to publish my app page I get the following error.

**Invalid Information
Your submission contains invalid data in the following fields:
You must choose at least one platform to be displayed**

From what I can see I've filled in all required fields, and I can't find any platform fields this message is referring to.

On the basic tab I have this set to a native iOS app.

Comment: Check this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10973122/you-must-select-at-least-one-listed-platform-to-display

Comment: In the end I added all the images (even optional ones) and it seemed to work. Very odd experience. Validation wasn't very helpful.